# Find field value that is found in most documents

Tags: search, elasticsearch, aggregate

Suppose there are documents that represents books and there is a field called *author*. What aggregation(s) can retrieve the *author* value that is found in most documents? Or rephrased, the author that has written most *books*?

In case it's not clear from the tag, the question is referring to **Elasticsearch**.

e.g.

```
{ 
  "name" : "Book1"
  "author" : "John" 
},
{ 
  "name" : "Book3"
  "author" : "Mike" 
},
{ 
  "name" : "Book2"
  "author" : "John" 
},
{ 
  "name" : "Book4"
  "author" : "Frank" 
}
```

For the above data, John must be returned since there are 2 documents with him as an author, while only one book by the others.

I've tried with value_count and cardinality, but this only returns the count and not the value itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this I found this is quite simple using **terms** aggregation. Left it, maybe other find this useful.

[Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts)

e.g. From data from above:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "author_count": {
            "terms": {
                "size": 2,
                "field": "book.author"
            }
     }
}
```